# sed doesn't remove wild card

Tags: bash, unix, scripting, ksh

I have have this string

```
[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]
```

Can you tell me how to remove the `[ ]`. I didn't succeed to do it with `sed`

I want that at last it will be like that:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

Comment: What did you try with `sed`? It's hard to suggest a solution without knowing what you've already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr -d '[]'` would remove the square brackets :

```
$ tr -d '[]' <<< "[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]"
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

To split, you could use a sed command like `'s/ /\n/'`

```
$ tr -d '[]' <<< "[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]" | sed 's/ /\n/'
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
echo [1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2] | sed 's/\[//' | sed 's/\]//'| sed 's/ /\n/'
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
echo '[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]' | sed -e 's/\[//' -e 's/]//' -e 's/ /\n/'
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]' | tr -d '[]'
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2

$ for derp in $(echo '[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]' | tr -d '[]'); do echo $derp; done
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

$ echo '[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]' | tr -d '[]' | sed 's/\s\+/\n/g'
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it as:

```
echo '[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]' | sed -r 's/\[|\]//g'
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

OR using posix sed:

```
echo '[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]' | sed 's/[][]//g'
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

Comment: You can avoid the escaping in your second command because `sed` assumes that an empty character class is not useful and takes `]` as a normal character, not as a closer.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
$ sed 's/\[\(.*\) \(.*\)\]/\1\n\2/' <<< "[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]"
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is only number, space and dot you can also use

```
echo '[1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2]' | sed "s/[^0-9. ]//g"
```

but the best is the posix one by anubhava just before